# How many ”words” can be formed by rearranging INQUISITIVE so that U does not immediately follow Q?

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt:

Step 1: Place the Q: $11$ ways

Step 2: Place the U accordingly: $9$ ways

Step 3: Place the remaining $9$ letters: $9!$ ways

So there are $11\times 9 \times 9!$ arrangements.

Can someone please check.

Comment: There are $11!/4!-10!/4!$ ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two small mistakes in your calculation:

- Placing Q at the end gives 10 possibilities to place U.

There are $10$ ways of placing Q with $9$ ways of placing U and $1$ way of placing Q with $10$  ways of placing U: $\boxed{10 \cdot 9 + 1 \cdot 10}$

- The permutations of the 4 I's need to be canceled out: $4!$

So, you get 
$$\frac{(10 \cdot 9 + 1 \cdot 10)\cdot 9!}{4!}$$

Another approach could be:

- All possible arrangements: $\frac{11!}{4!}$
- Arrangements with QU together: $\frac{10!}{4!}$

Subtraction gives the arrangements where U does not directly follow Q:
$$\frac{11!}{4!} - \frac{10!}{4!} = \frac{11!-10!}{4!}$$

Comment: Well, QU isn't allowed however UQ is allowed

Comment: Exactly. So, it is. :-)

Answer (score 0):

- All possible arrangements: $\frac{11!}{4!}$
- Arrangements with QU appear=$\frac{\text{ Arrangements where Q and U appear together}}{2}=\frac{10!}{2.4!}$

Subtraction gives the arrangements where U does not directly follow Q:
$$\frac{11!}{4!} - \frac{10!}{2.4!} = \frac{11!-\frac{10!}{2}}{4!}$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  If QU is treated as an object, then we have ten objects to arrange, including four copies of I, which can be done in $\frac{10!}{4!}$ ways.  The number of arrangements in which QU can appear together is twice that since Q can appear before or after U.

Comment: Same thing I had done bro. Can you write the answer based on what you are explaining?

Comment: I do not know according to you where I did wrong? -_-

Comment: Why did you divide by 2? @user581912

Comment: @user581912  If you want to count the number of arrangements where Q and U appear together, place them in a box.  Then we have ten objects to arrange, including four copies of I.  Choose four of the ten positions for the copies of I, which can be done in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways.  The other six objects are distinct, so they can be arranged in $6!$ ways.  The Q and U can be arranged in the box in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are $$\binom{10}{4}6!2! = \frac{10!}{4!6!} \cdot 6! 2! = \frac{2 \cdot 10!}{4!}$$ arrangements in which Q and U are together.

Comment: @user581912  Dividing the number of arrangements in which Q and U are together by $2$ gives the correct answer.  What you failed to take into account is that Q could appear before or after U if the two letters are together.  It is simpler to simply consider QU as a single object.  We then have four copies of I and six other objects to arrange.  We can choose four positions for the copies of I in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways and arrange the six distinct objects in $6!$ ways, which gives $$\binom{10}{4}6! = \frac{10!}{4!6!} \cdot 6! = \frac{10!}{4!}$$ arrangements in which U immediately follows Q.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oh God. I did the same. I considered Q and U Together. Hence they are $\frac{10!}{4!}$ ways. In those $\frac{10!}{4!}$ There are two cases QU appears or UQ appears. Since we want only one I divided it by two. Don't know what's wrong with you. You cannot directly say anyone did wrong without enquiring. You are putting negatively for me -_-. You can say you didn't understand and then judge  werther one is correct or not

Comment: @user581912 Before you divided by $2$, you failed to multiply $\frac{10!}{4!}$ by the $2!$ orders in which the letters Q and U could appear if they appear consecutively.  Therefore, your final answer for the case in which they appear in the order QU should be $\frac{10!}{4!}$.